# Move files on ftp

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel

I am working with Apache Camel Spring Framework. I have a component FTP (to get files from ftp) and Bean (process files and store it in database). All I have missing is when I process those files and store it in database I have to check if insert or update was successful (this is working too). If the action is successful I have to move the file to another folder on ftp, if it is unsuccessful I have to move it to a different folder on ftp.

So I am asking if there is a simple way to copy the file from location dirA to dirB

Comment: The Camel route is simple. FTP -> Bean. Bean gets the message (which is file from FTP) and inserts it in database. I can check if insert was successful or not, I only need to know how to move the file from one folder to another. For example: Reading the file on location  __ftp://10.10.10.10/toRead/somefile.csv_ -> process it and store it in database -> move it to __ftp://10.10.10.10/inDB/_ (that's the part I am missing). I think that's the best explanation I can offer. I hope you will understand it

Comment: See the moveFailed option - http://camel.apache.org/file2

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know is here [Apache Camel: File2](http://camel.apache.org/file2)
Search for `move` and `moveFailed`.

If insert was not successful you may throw a [CamelException](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelException.html). Camel will then move the file to the folder you specified.

```
ftp://10.10.10.10/toRead?move=inDB&moveFailed=notInDB
```

Answer (score 0):

As I do not have your code, I will just answer by showing how I would manage such case:

Make two separate routes according to the result of the bean processing.

```
from("{{your.ftp.source}}")
    .bean( new ProcessAndStoreFileBean())
    .choice()
        .when(property("fileProcessingResult").equalsTo(true))
            .to("ftp://yourserver/Destination/Folder/Success")
        .otherwise()
            .to("ftp://yourserver/Destination/Folder/Failure")
    .end();
```

and in the Bean method I would just make:

```
class ProcessAndStoreFileBean {

    @Handler
    public void processAndSaveInDb(Exchange exchange){

        // many line to do the job...

        if( success ) 
            exchange.setProperty("fileProcessingResult", true);
        else{
            exchange.setProperty("fileProcessingResult", false);
    }
}
```