# Move option using camel ftp component not working

Tags: apache-camel

I am using camel version 2.16.0.

I am trying to send some files through ftp camel component and move them to another location after finishing the transmission.

I am using the "ftp://127.0.0.1/folder1/folder2?username=dev_user&passiveMode=true&password=dev_password&maximumReconnectAttempts=500&reconnectDelay=300000&move=folder3" route.

My files are sent properly, but not moved from Folder2 to Folder3 as I would expect after finishing the transmission.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!
Marcelo

Comment: Check the logs and research yourself more what may happen.

Comment: Of course I already checked the camel logs. The route is stablished properly, and no exception is thrown. I already used this move functionality for a FILE route, without any issues. The FTP route is the one that is not working

Comment: how are you running this route? Are you deploying it somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move -option exists only for the consumer (from), not for the producer (to). Camel's FTP-component uses the File2-component, please study the API http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

If however you are using consumer, then it could be e.g. permission issue and you should study the logs.

Comment: I read that part of the documentation, but I though it would work based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556558/move-files-on-ftp

Comment: Consumer was used also in your referenced case: move if all ok, or moveFailed if an exception was thrown on DB-insert. You may want to use tempPrefix or tempFileName from File2-producer to achieve your goal.

Comment: you are right, I misunderstood, it is a consumer indeed, thank you

Comment: I supose I am going to need to perform this using ftp commands, as the move operation is supported by the protocol